# Create Entity Manger runtime with connection pooling in Spring and eclipse Link JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to create a entity manager at runtime which will have connection pooling.
Data base details will be provided by user and based on that we need to create one entity manager which will have connection pooling.
I am using spring MVC , Eclipse Link JPA.
I tried some solution but either they are working with @configuration annotation which is not ideal for me.
One solution is working fine but i am not able to maintain connection pooling.
below is code which is working fine but not able to add support for connection pooling.

```
public static EntityManager getEntityManager(){
        EntityManagerFactory emf;
        Map properties = new HashMap();
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SampleDB");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.user", "root");
        properties.put("eclipselink.jdbc.password", "root");
        //emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jpablogPUnit");
        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("datajpa",properties);
        return  (EntityManager) emf.createEntityManager(); 
    }
```

Comment: You need an `EntityManagerFactory` and not an `EntityManager`.

Comment: Deinum , agree with you. is there any way you are aware ? we can have this factory with connection pooling ?

Comment: Check the eclipselink documentation on how to configure it.

Comment: What sort of connection pooling support are you looking for? What you've shown lets Eclipselink handle pooling the connections internally, using the defaults. See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/persistenceproperties_ref.htm#CHDICECH2 and https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool.htm for specific properties to control the connection pools, or you can pass in your own datasource instance